# Integrating YOLOv8 to an Transformer Model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolo, yolov8

I need help with adding [YOLOv8 model](https://docs.ultralytics.com/models/yolov8/) to this below code instead of using an InceptionV3 to extract the image features for my project. I need to pass the detected objects and extracted features from the YOLOv8 model to generate the caption using the transformer.

```
def CNN_Encoder_Incep():
    inception_v3 = tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(
        include_top=False,
        weights='imagenet'
    )
    inception_v3.trainable = False

    output = inception_v3.output
    output = tf.keras.layers.Reshape(
        (-1, output.shape[-1]))(output)

    cnn_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inception_v3.input, output)
    return cnn_model

class ImageCaptioningModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, cnn_model, encoder, decoder, image_aug=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.cnn_model = cnn_model
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.image_aug = image_aug
        self.loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="loss")
        self.acc_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="accuracy")


    def calculate_loss(self, y_true, y_pred, mask):
        loss = self.loss(y_true, y_pred)
        mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=loss.dtype)
        loss *= mask
        return tf.reduce_sum(loss) / tf.reduce_sum(mask)


    def calculate_accuracy(self, y_true, y_pred, mask):
        accuracy = tf.equal(y_true, tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=2))
        accuracy = tf.math.logical_and(mask, accuracy)
        accuracy = tf.cast(accuracy, dtype=tf.float32)
        mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=tf.float32)
        return tf.reduce_sum(accuracy) / tf.reduce_sum(mask)


    def compute_loss_and_acc(self, img_embed, captions, training=True):
        encoder_output = self.encoder(img_embed, training=True)
        y_input = captions[:, :-1]
        y_true = captions[:, 1:]
        mask = (y_true != 0)
        y_pred = self.decoder(
            y_input, encoder_output, training=True, mask=mask
        )
        loss = self.calculate_loss(y_true, y_pred, mask)
        acc = self.calculate_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, mask)
        return loss, acc


    def train_step(self, batch):
        imgs, captions = batch

        if self.image_aug:
            imgs = self.image_aug(imgs)

        img_embed = self.cnn_model(imgs)

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            loss, acc = self.compute_loss_and_acc(
                img_embed, captions
            )

        train_vars = (
            self.encoder.trainable_variables + self.decoder.trainable_variables
        )
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, train_vars)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, train_vars))
        self.loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        self.acc_tracker.update_state(acc)

        return {"loss": self.loss_tracker.result(), "acc": self.acc_tracker.result()}


    def test_step(self, batch):
        imgs, captions = batch

        img_embed = self.cnn_model(imgs)

        loss, acc = self.compute_loss_and_acc(
            img_embed, captions, training=False
        )

        self.loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        self.acc_tracker.update_state(acc)

        return {"loss": self.loss_tracker.result(), "acc": self.acc_tracker.result()}

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [self.loss_tracker, self.acc_tracker]

cnn_model = CNN_Encoder_Incep()
caption_model = ImageCaptioningModel(
    cnn_model=cnn_model, encoder=encoder, decoder=decoder, image_aug=image_augmentation,
)
```

I tried doing this but i keep getting multiple errors when i try to pass this to the cnn_model variable.

```
def CNN_Encoder():
    yolov8_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./content/yolov8n_objdet_oidv7_640x640.pt')
    yolov8_model.trainable = False
    output = yolov8_model.output
    output = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1, output.shape[-1]))(output)
    cnn_model = tf.keras.models.Model(yolov8_model.input, output)
    cnn_model_onnx = cnn_model.export(format='onnx')
    return cnn_model
```

Answer (score 0):

The .pt file extension means that `./content/yolov8n_objdet_oidv7_640x640.pt` is most likely a pytorch state dict, they are usually saved with either the .pt or .pth file extension.

If you want to load a pre-trained YOLOv8 model into a keras model object you can do it with [KerasCV](https://keras.io/keras_cv/). Either with `keras_cv.models.YOLOV8Backbone.from_preset()` if you just want the backbone, or with `keras_cv.models.YOLOV8Detector()` for the whole object detection model.

In your case you can try `yolov8_model = keras_cv.models.YOLOV8Backbone.from_preset("yolo_v8_xs_backbone_coco")` to load YOLOv8-nano weights pre-trained on the COCO dataset.